# Is there a way to extract the position from a live chess game while it's happening in chess.com?

Tags: online-chess, pgn, chess.com

I would like to make something that has the capability to convert a chess game in chess.com to a text-to-speech output (for example to play blindfolded.) I know this has been made before, but I'm not looking for the product but rather the process. Is there a way to extract moves as they are being made or the PGN or something like that from a live chess.com game while it's happening? Assume I know everything I need to know, just give me the explanation if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just scrape the HTML. Here's a picture of the HTML that chess.com uses to store moves:

[image]

Most modern languages have ways of scraping HTML on update, so this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you click the "Explorer" icon during the game, it will open the Opening Explorer page in a new window. The URL of the page will contain the move list. For example:

`https://www.chess.com/explorer?moveList=e4+e5+Nf3+Nc6`

If you want the actual PGN, it can also easily be accessed from that page using the normal buttons.

I assume there's some limit as to how many moves are allowed, although I just tried it 35 moves into a game and it still had all the moves.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to export this in some way?